# Does my jquery get request to server get aborted after timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a web app.

It is written in asp.net, javascript and jquery.

I have a timer on the page.  It will 'ping' my server every 100ms (I know this is not guarantted due to the nature of timers in javascript).

So, this is my code:

```
function GetImageStatus() {
    var val = url + '/Mobile/isNewFrame.ashx?Alias=' + Alias + '&CamIndex=' + camIndex + '&Version=' + version + '&GuidLogOn=' + guidLogOn;
    jQuery.get(val)
    .success(function (data) {
        //invalid session
        if (data == '-2') {
            document.location.reload(true);
        }
        else {
            //do something useful
        }
    })
    .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var ct = XMLHttpRequest.errorThrown;
        $("#divVersion").html(ct);
    });
}


function Start()
{
    if (timer4x4) window.clearTimeout(timer4x4);
    timer4x4 = window.setTimeout(GetImageStatus, tmrInterval);
}

var timer4x4;
var tmrInterval = 100;
```

So, my question is this.  If the ping/get call takes longer than my tmrInterval is the call aborted before the next call is initiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I suggest using jQuery [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with timeout option such as :

```
$.ajax({
    url: val,
    type: 'GET',
    timeout: tmrInterval,
    success: function (data) {
        //invalid session
        if (data == '-2') {
            document.location.reload(true);
        }
        else {
            //do something useful
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var ct = XMLHttpRequest.errorThrown;
        $("#divVersion").html(ct);
    }
    });
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer.  I do use ajax/jquery calls quite a lot in this app).  I was concerned about using a timer call within an ajax function as this would cause (I presume) an asynchronous behaviour which could overload my server.  Also, aborting the call client side does not abort the processing code on the server side.  Thanks for your thoughts though..

Comment: but I will test this though :)

Comment: Aborting server side processing should be done server side I think.

Comment: Hi, yes and whilst not impossible it does make the code more complex. But I will test ur suggestion soon and get back to you. Many thanks

Comment: Maybe not necessarily more complex. When you get a 'GET' request on this address and previous processing isn't done then either abort it or don't process with the new call :)

Comment: Hi,  That is a good way of looking at it. I like that. I think that with your original post deserves the 'green tick'  Excellent..

Comment: Thanks ! Pleased to help you :)